# how can i call a function in a smart contract from an abi json file smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, abi

i have the abi json file for a contract and i want to use its functions in my smart contract.
is there any way to do it?

for example i have a contractA.sol and contractB.jsonn in my contractA i want to call a function fncA in the contractB, but contractB is elready deployed and i just have its abi file.
i imported the json file to my contract but then i don't know how to fetch its functions and use them.

```
import '../abis/contractB.json'
contract contractA {
.
.
.
// i want to use funcA from contractB contract here.
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately solidity doesn't supports using json ABIs as interface.

You can use some tools like this https://gnidan.github.io/abi-to-sol/ to generate the interface, then copy it into a 'IContractB.sol` file, which can be imported in your 'ContractA.sol'.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it in a very few steps. just use the abi of a particular function and paste it in a new abi of a smart contract on which your are currently working and call that method just using web3.

please reply if you have any queries.